# Tableau: how can I filter dimensions/metrics on the dashboard based on the user's previous selection

Tags: tableau-api

I just started working with Tableau and I fail to find a way to filter dimensions/metrics on the dashboard based on the user's previous selection.

We use MongoDB NoSQL database to store various events sent from our system.
Event consist of Key-Value pairs (translated to metrics and dimensions), each event has a unique Id (EventType) and a list of parameters.
The number of parameters per EventType is constant but vary between event types.

When we connect the Events catalog to Tableau (using MongoDB BI connector) we receive a flat table with all possible keys while only the ones that apply to the specific event has a value.

Since we have a lot of event types and a large number of possible keys (between them) this cause problems when using the dashboard.
The user see a flat list of all possible dimensions and metrics with no correlation between them.
He can not know which metric apply to which eventType.

How can I can guide Tableau to present/highlight only the relevant dimensions / metrics, based on the EventType selected by the user?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You click on the down arrow in the top right of the filter and then select **Only Show Relevant Values**.

[Click for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGnGE.png)